# Android Studio definir uma string em varias textview

Tags: android, string

estou estudando o Android Studio e acabei me deparando com um problema, e precisava de uma luz.

Eu fiz varias textView na tela do meu aplicativo
e quando eu apertar um botão eu mudaria o conteudo de todas textView que estão na tela.

No caso eu estava usando findViewById(); e o setText(); para mudar o conteúdo de cada uma delas, e está dando certo assim.

Mais no caso são varias textview e algumas delas receberão o mesmo valor por exemplo 10 delas vou por a mesma String e outras 3 vão receber uma string diferente

Pensando no fato de ter varias textview que receberão a mesma string, existe algum modo de criar uma especie de clone dela que quando ela mudar as outras mudam juntas? para diminuir os comandos repetitivos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o atributo `android:setTag="sua-tag"` no *XML* ou o método `textView.setTag("sua-tag")`.

**Exemplo:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="br.com.valdeirsantana.stackoverflow.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="sua-tag"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.392" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="sua-tag"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.247" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="sua-tag"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.14" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="sua-tag"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.032" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="148dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="271dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Feito isso basta filtrar todos os elementos do tipo `textView` que possuem a *tag* definida.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ViewGroup container;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        container = findViewById(R.id.container);

        findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                /* Percorre todos os filhos da view Container */
                for (int count = 0; count < container.getChildCount(); count++) {

                    /* Captura a view filho */
                    View currentView = container.getChildAt(count);

                    /* Verifica se ela é do tipo TextView, converte a tag para String e verifica se é igual a tag definida */
                    if ( currentView instanceof TextView && String.valueOf(currentView.getTag()).equals("sua-tag")) {
                        ((TextView) currentView).setText("Novo Texto");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: cara muito obrigado era isso que queria aprender vlw !!!